# Failed to resolve SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'

Tags: xamarin.android

I just created a project on Xamarin and I immediately have 2 problems, and as I understand they are interconnected, problem 1: the sdk package seems to be missing, I downloaded all the packages that are available in the android package manager, but the problem remains the same problem in visual studio:
Failed to resolve SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'. One of the verification messages below indicates why the SDK could not be resolved. Investigate and resolve the issue to ensure that you specify the SDK correctly.
The .NET SDK cannot be found. Make sure the package is installed, the PATH is set to the correct architecture, and the version listed in the global.json file (if present) matches the one installed.
NuGetSdkResolver could not resolve this SDK because the version was not specified in the project or global.json.
MSB4276: The standard SDK resolver failed to resolve the SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" because the directory "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk" is not exists. NFSMan.Android C:\Users\Sporwiev\source\repos\NFSMan\NFSMan\NFSMan\NFSMan.csproj

I tried to download all the packages but it didn't help.

Comment: You could try [Repairing Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) using Visual Studio Installer

Comment: Have you tried using ```dotnet --info``` in cmd to to see if the .NET information displays correctly?